# Is there any use for Reputation Points?

Tags: scribblenauts-unmasked

I was wondering if the Reputation Points earned by creating new words can be utilized in any sort of way. Can they?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you don't know this, you probably haven't gotten far into the game. As stated on [this site](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/scribblenauts-unmasked-a-dc-comics-adventure-review), Reputation Points can be used to unlock access to new areas.